# How to skip using Photos app whem importing photos

Tags: finder, photos, photos.app, import

I prefer to keep sorted/labeled folders of all of my iphone photos via finder and a NAS system. With more and more system updates and phone/iMac changes, I am finding that now when I go to import photos from phone to iMac I can't bypass the stupid "photos" app.

Can anyone help me? I saw someone's suggestion about using image capture application, but I can't find that either.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS version(s), steps you're taking that cause the problem, etc.  Please see [ask] for tips on how to ask questions that have a good at being answered.

Comment: Image Capture should be in the Applications folder. What version of macOS is running on your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Image Capture](https://support.apple.com/guide/image-capture/transfer-images-imgcp1003/mac) to save you photos to a folder somewhere. Image capture will bring up a list of photos and you can select which ones to save.

There is also an app [IExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer?gclid=CjwKCAjwxev3BRBBEiwAiB_PWMUcln9-n3i9ih-0MPFqwQ8OZVeeWrScTT6XCFe57o8he51Gg6SynRoCFagQAvD_BwE) which allows you to just transfer photos from your device to another.  Just select one or all photos and copy to a folder.

Comment: Thank you. I went to you tube also and found a gentleman that furhter talked about locating image capture. It did not show up in spotlight initially for me. Thankyou for your help too.